# Move Toolbar to the bottom in UWP with PlatformConfiguration (Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

Trying out the new PlatformConfiguration in `Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.166-pre4` but moving the Toolbar to the bottom on UWP just doesn't want to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.WindowsSpecific;

namespace FormsToolBarDemo
{
    public partial class MainPage:ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.On<Windows>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, after trying every possible combination of `SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom)`, I found out a few things:

- Toolbar Placement can only be set application wide, not per page
- Toolbar Placement can only be set on a `NavigationPage`

So what you can do, when you want to place the toolbar at the bottom, you can set it application wide by attaching the Toolbar Placement to the `App` classes `MainPage` property.

```
public App()
{
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    MainPage.On<Windows>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);
}
```