# Toolbar goes bottom in Xamarin.Forms.UWP (only in mobile deployment)

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I'm experiencing an odd situation here. I have a TabbedPage and 4 NavigationPages inside it. I added a toolbar with only an icon in it. When I deploy my project in my *Local Machine* , everything looks good ([print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjYGg.png)). But when I deploy the project on my *WP10* device, this happens: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb1cm.png). For absolutely no reason, my toolbar goes at the bottom of my screen. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40484343/move-toolbar-to-the-bottom-in-uwp-with-platformconfiguration-xamarin-forms-2-3) answer, and I tried to implement it, but it throws me an error (**Note:** I updated my whole solution to Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.168).

My *MainPage.xaml* code is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<local:CustomTabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:_TIF_Xamarin;assembly=_TIF_Xamarin"
            x:Class="_TIF_Xamarin.MainPage">

     <local:CustomTabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
       <ToolbarItem Name="tool">
         <ToolbarItem.Icon>
           <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"
                       Android="dethbarlogo.png"
                       WinPhone="logosearch.png" />
           </ToolbarItem.Icon>
         </ToolbarItem>
       </local:CustomTabbedPage.ToolbarItems>

  <!--4 different tabs, which also are Navigation Pages-->
  <NavigationPage Title="Home">
    <x:Arguments>
      <local:HomePage />
    </x:Arguments>
  </NavigationPage>

  <NavigationPage Title="Exhibitor">
    <x:Arguments>
      <local:ExhibitorsPage />
    </x:Arguments>
  </NavigationPage>

  <NavigationPage Title="Exhibits">
    <x:Arguments>
      <local:ExhibitsPage />
    </x:Arguments>
  </NavigationPage>

  <NavigationPage Title="More">
    <x:Arguments>
      <local:MorePage />
    </x:Arguments>
  </NavigationPage>

</TabbedPage>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just as an explanation of what you're seeing there, the toolbar goes to the bottom for the Windows Mobile Phone project because that's the standard location for a toolbar on a Windows Phone. So the behaviour you're seeing is exactly what I'd expect from Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks. But [here](http://imgur.com/a/nyh75) is a screenshot from the previous Xamarin.Forms version (2.3.2.127), in which the toolbar displays at the top of my app. I switched to the latest version, in order to get rid [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40816708/irritating-blank-space-between-title-bar-and-tabs-in-xamarin-forms-uwp-project). So, I'm guessing that this behaviour is just a bug. Thanks for your time, anyway